# How to write test class for salesforce email template

Tags: unit-testing

I'm struggling to write a test class for visualforce email template that I have created as per business requirements but I don't know who to cover "get' methods in the test class.. I spent long hours doing research on google unfortunately I haven't found anything helpful.

I tried many ways to cover 'get' method in test class like below

```
myClass cls = new myClass;
cls.getMethod();
cls.getProperty = 'test';
```

but it's giving me the error message "List index out of bounds: 0" because I'm calling another method in getter and that methods takes list of records

```
Controller Class: 
public class JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls {
  
  public string jobId {get; set;}
  // public string jUrl{get; }
  // public  string clientUrl {get; }
  // public string endclientUrl {get;}
   public static list<job__c> jobs;
    
  public JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls()
    {
        jobs = [select j.Id,j.name,j.other_location__c,j.account__c,j.account__r.id, j.account__r.name,j.Job_Start_Date__c,j.Job_End_Date__c,j.Job_Status__c,j.account__r.Spreadsheet_SOPs__c,
                j.account__r.Facility_SOPs__c,j.End_Client__c,End_Client__r.id,j.End_Client__r.name,j.End_Client__r.Spreadsheet_SOPs__c, j.End_Client__r.Facility_SOPs__c from Job__c j where Id=:jobId];
         system.debug('-------------------------------------jobId '+jobId);
    } 
    public list<job__c> getjbs()
    {
        jobs = [select j.Id,j.name,j.other_location__c,j.account__c, j.account__r.name,j.Job_Start_Date__c,j.Job_End_Date__c,j.Job_Status__c,j.account__r.Spreadsheet_SOPs__c,
                j.account__r.Facility_SOPs__c,j.End_Client__c,j.End_Client__r.name,j.End_Client__r.Spreadsheet_SOPs__c, j.End_Client__r.Facility_SOPs__c from Job__c j where Id=:jobId];
         system.debug('-------------------------------------jobId '+jobId);
        return jobs;
    }

Public static string generatejobUrl(list<job__c> jobs)
{
   
    string jurl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/'+jobs[0].Id;
    return jurl;
}
Public static string generateclientUrl(list<job__c> jobs)
{
    string cUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+jobs[0].account__r.id;
    return cUrl;
}
Public static string generateEndclientUrl(list<job__c> jobs)
{
    string endCUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+jobs[0].end_client__r.id;
   return endCUrl;
}

 public String getjUrl()
 {    
      string jbUrl;
      list<job__c> jobs = [select Id,name from Job__c where Id=:jobId];
      jbUrl= System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/'+jobs[0].Id;
     return jbUrl;
 }
  public string clientUrl
  {
      get { return generateclientUrl(jobs); }
  }
 public string endclientUrl
 {
     get { return generateEndclientUrl(jobs); }
 } 
}





Test class I have written so far: 
@isTest(seeAllData=  true)
Public class JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls_test {
 
 @isTest
 public static void createJob()
 {
     string clienturl;
     string endClienturl;
     string joburl;
     list<job__c> jobs = new list<job__c>();
      Account a = new account(name='ghghghg',type='Other',  Account_Status__c='Active',phone='9090909090');
            insert a;
            Contact contact = new Contact(FirstName='John',LastName='Adams',email='test@gamil.com',phone='14243443', accountid = a.id);
            insert contact;
           // Opportunity o  = [Select id, Name, CloseDate ,Location__c ,AccountId from opportunity limit 1];
            Job__c job = new Job__c();
                        job.Name = 'NewJob'; // Set to match test record
                        job.X_KOL__c = false; // Set to match test record
                        job.DE_Job_Type__c = null;  // Set to match test record
                        job.Job_Name_Subject__c = 'TestJob';
                        job.Job_Start_Date__c = Date.today();
                        job.End_Client__c = a.Id;
                        job.Other_Location__c = 'SOS'; // Set to match test record
                        job.PM__c = 'Amber Anderson';
                        job.Booked_By__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
                        job.Account_Manager_COE__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
                        job.Account__c = a.Id;
                        job.Contact__c = contact.Id;
                        job.Respondent_Type__c = 'Acne';
                        job.Job_Status__c = 'Tentative';
                        job.Job_Qualification__c = 'Qualitative';
                        job.Recruitment_Method__c = 'Client List';
                        job.On_Site_Recruits__c = 5;
                        job.Off_Site_Recruits__c = 5;
                        job.London_Project_Number__c = 'Valyria';
                        job.Recruiting_Begin_Date__c = Date.today();
                        jobs.add(job);
     if(jobs.size()>0)
     {
         insert jobs;
     }
 
  test.startTest();

  clienturl = JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls.generateclientUrl(jobs);
  endClienturl = JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls.generateEndclientUrl(jobs);
  joburl = JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls.generatejobUrl(jobs);
  
  Test.stopTest();
     string cUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+jobs[0].account__r.id;
     string Eurl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+jobs[0].end_client__r.id;
     string jUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/'+jobs[0].Id;
   system.assertEquals(clienturl, cUrl);
   system.assertEquals(endClienturl, Eurl);
   system.assertEquals(joburl, jUrl);

JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls cls = new JobChangesEmail_ComplianceTeam_Cls();
     cls.getjbs();
     string id = cls.jobId;
     id =  [select id from job__c limit 1].id;
     system.assertNotEquals(id,job.id);
 }
}
```

above test class is not covering get methods or properties